# Give a grid column with text content 100% width

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a ListBox that uses the following template:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image Source="{Binding Property3}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Width="64"/> 
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Property2}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem I'm having is with the middle column. The length of the text in the middle column determines the grid's width. What's the best way to make the grid extend to 100% of the page's width without using exact values for width? Or is this impossible? I tried quite a number of suggestions from here (Ex. setting HorizontalContentAlignment on the ListBox) to no avail.

EDIT: Here's the full page, minimal code to highlight the problem:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="FoursquareDemo.SandboxPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding Property3}" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="64" Width="64"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Property1}"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding Property2}" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
            </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

<ListBox x:Name="LayoutRoot" DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource SampleDataSource}}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Collection}" />
```

Comment: Your grid already extends to the full length of its container. So if it doesn't extend to the page's full width, the problem is with your grid's parent.

Comment: You're right, I just don't understand what parent element seems to be doing this. The ListBox seems to take up the width of the page (according to background color and query for property), but nothing I do to the ListBox or the root Grid in the template seems to do anything.

Also, if I replace the TextBlock in column 1 with an Image, it consumes the entire space (albeit stretched). So it seems to only behave like this with text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

ListBoxItems do not expand to the full width of the ListBox. It's better to use a LongListSelector in this case. It seems like overkill, but it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you could approach the problem.

1) Set the Margin of the Grid to Margin = "0,0,0,0"

This basically sets the offset of the Grid to 0 for "Left, Top, Right, Bottom"

2)If the above does not work, check the parent Grid. And set the Margin of the Parent Grid to the same as mentioned. It is ok if you change the values of Top and Bottom according to your design. However, if you wish to have the length of the Grid to take up the entire Width, make sure you set the left and right margin values to 0.

Comment: No dice :(. I tried that, but it didn't make any change to the layout. Thank you though!

Comment: Another approach: Try using a StackPanel instead of a Grid. See if that solves the issue. 
Set the Margin of the StackPanel as 0,0,0,0, and then add the Image, and the 2 Textbox within in the Stackpanel.

Comment: A stack panel didn't work either. Each element takes up the full width and subsequent elements are placed on the next line. However, I found the answer: it seems like ListBoxItems don't expand to full width. Changing it to a LongListSelector did the trick.